# How to break the tuple brackets within a list?

Tags: python

I have a list of data:

```
[[], [], [(2, 3), (2, 7), (3, 2), (7, 2)], [(2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 7), (7, 3)], [], [], [], [(2, 7), (3, 7), (7, 2), (7, 3)], [], []]
```

I want to remove the brackets in the tuple so that `[(2, 3), (2, 7), (3, 2), (7, 2)]` will become `(2,3,2,7,3,2,7,2)`.

Is there a shortcut to do this?

Comment: I don't think the dupe close is correct. OP seems to want to keep the outermost list and just unpack the inner lists. NPE has effectively answered this problem in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
In [6]: l = [[], [], [(2, 3), (2, 7), (3, 2), (7, 2)], [(2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 7), (7, 3)], [], [], [], [(2, 7), (3, 7), (7, 2), (7, 3)], [], []]

In [7]: [tuple(itertools.chain(*el)) for el in l]
Out[7]: 
[(),
 (),
 (2, 3, 2, 7, 3, 2, 7, 2),
 (2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 7, 7, 3),
 (),
 (),
 (),
 (2, 7, 3, 7, 7, 2, 7, 3),
 (),
 ()]
```

Comment: `[tuple(itertools.chain(*el)) if el else el for el in l]` I think the empty list should not be converted to tuple object.

Comment: @TanveerAlam: I too think that. However, I'd rather not second-guess  OP's requirements (which are ambiguous on this).

Comment: `[tuple(np.array(ls).flatten()) for ls in l]` also gives us the same result.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking to flatten a list. In python you can do that with a compound list comprehension

```
data = [(2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 7), (7, 3)]
flattend = [item for lst in data for item in lst]
```

Comment: This doesn't work. This returns a list of tuples which don't match what the OP wants.